# KDB; stripping characters from column of symbols

Tags: symbols, kdb, q-lang

Any ideas how to do this nicely in KDB?

Consider the table

```
X:([]a:1 2 3;b:`abc11`abc22`abc33;c:10 20 30)
```

I now want a new table Y that has the "abc" stripped out of the symbols in the second column, such that:

```
Y:([]a:1 2 3;b:`11`22`33;c:10 20 30)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3;b:`abc11`abc22`abc33;c:10 20 30)
q)t
a b     c
----------
1 abc11 10
2 abc22 20
3 abc33 30
```

Strip the first three characters:

```
q)update `$3_'string b from t
a b    c
---------
1 11 10
2 22 20
3 33 30
```

Or search and replace:

```
q)update `$ssr[;"abc";""] each string b from t
a b    c
---------
1 11 10
2 22 20
3 33 30
```

If the table is large and has many repeating items, consider using .Q.fu:

```
q)t:1000000#([]a:1 2 3;b:`abc11`abc22`abc33;c:10 20 30)
q)\t r1:update `$3_'string b from t
111
q)\t r2:update .Q.fu[{`$3_'string x};b] from t
5
q)r1~r2
1b
```

Comment: don't forget to cast back to `symbol.

Comment: nice tip on using .Q.fu

Answer (score 1):

Using lambdas as suggested in the other answer is fine, but not necessary for this question. If something can be achieved using adverbs alone, that is usually preferable.

```
Y: update `$ 3_'string b from X
```

is shorter and more readable. On my machine it also runs twice as fast.

```
Y: update `$ ssr[;"abc";""] each string b from X
```

only runs slightly faster. I've cast both back to `symbol.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @Ryan Hamilton's answer, here is an example if you want to strip the last two characters:

```
q)update `$-2_'string b from t
a b    c
---------
1 abc 10
2 abc 20
3 abc 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both mentioned solution (by ryan and mollmerx) on large database(100000 rows) and I got following results:

`ssr` took around 645ms (average)

`cut` version took around 40 ms (average)

I tried another solution which proved to be much faster. If we use dictionary behavior of a table:

```
t[`b]:  `$3_'string t`b
```

This took around 12 ms on an average.

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is more general and you want to remove everything before your first numeric then you could do something like below. You could further generalize to all columns with symbol type

```
q)show r1:update b:`${(first each where each x in .Q.n)_'x}string b from X
a b  c
-------
1 11 10
2 22 20
3 33 30
q)show r2:@[X; exec c from meta X where t="s"; `${(first each where each x in .Q.n)_'x}string@]
a b  c
-------
1 11 10
2 22 20
3 33 30
q)r1~r2
1b
```

Granted, I don't know what your set up is, but on my machine, this is quite quick. Not nearly as quick as your dictionary approach, but might be worth the sacrifice for the generality

```
q)\ts update b:`${(first each where each x in .Q.n)_'x}string b from X
69 12746848j
```